# Bootstrap 4, model won't open

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I can't figure out why my modal won't open. It's completely not visible. When I click on the a tag for the model to open, it just opens the #, so scrolls back to top. This is the code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid signup-container">
<div class="row signup-row">
    <div class="col-md-12 signup-col">
        <div class="signup-section-text">
            <h4 class="signup-text">Aanmelden</h4>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            This is body
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input class="btn btn-default" value="Close">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModal">Meer informatie</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="signup-button">
            <h5 class="hero-title mx-auto">Wordt een held!</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done this wrong

`<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModal">Meer informatie</a>`

`data-target="#myModal"` will contain `#`

Try this

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid signup-container">
        <div class="row signup-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 signup-col">
                <div class="signup-section-text">
                    <h4 class="signup-text">Aanmelden</h4>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h1>Title</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    This is body
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Meer informatie</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="signup-button">
                    <h5 class="hero-title mx-auto">Wordt een held!</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please correct the data-target attribute into data-target="#myModal" that contain #.